# How to work with Canvas GoJS in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, canvas, selenium-webdriver, gojs

We have diagram application which is built using Canvas and GoJS. There are many controls in toolbox and I would like to drag particular element to blank area.

I have tried by actions method but that is not working.

I tried code :

```
actions.moveToElement(paletteCanvas, palette_node_x, palette_node_y);
        actions.clickAndHold();
        //Dragging selected node a little bit to make it work. 
        actions.moveToElement(paletteCanvas, palette_node_x, palette_node_y+50 );
        //Now perform the actual move
        actions.moveToElement(flowCanvas, diagramOffsetX , diagramOffsetY);
        actions.release();
        actions.perform();
```

Also it is hard to find offsets for element. Is there any there way by which I can automate following using selenium :

1. Drag and Drop any control fro toolbox
2. Select any particular control from tool box

Any possibility to work by JSexecutor?

Answer (score 1):

These links might be helpful to you:

http://forum.nwoods.com/t/how-to-implement-selenium-test-cases-for-canvas/5195
http://forum.nwoods.com/t/locating-elements-on-canvas-by-selenium-webdriver/5509
http://forum.nwoods.com/t/simulate-selectionadorrnmenttemplate-click-selenium/6134